# How to edit the audio in an avi/wma video

Tags: audio, processing, screencasts

I am creating an instructional video and I want to add some music to the intro and ending.

Currently I record my video with SnagIt witch saves the video as an AVI but apparently encodes with wma.

I tried to use Audacity to edit the audio and it told me it could not with the error: "wma-proprietary".

So, is there a way to edit (or is there a cooler (free) screen capture tool that saves in a more universal format)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously I've used Windows Movie Maker that is on my Win XP machine and I've really liked it, oh and it's free. Just open the video you've made in Win Movie Maker and there's a channel there where you can add your own music or narrate and that's what I've used to put background music on my vids.

Answer (score 2):

[Camstudio](http://camstudio.org/) is a free screen capture tool that IIRC saves as AVI.  It would certainly be worth a shot.  (please ignore the fact that the site looks like a spammy sales page, I have no idea why they designed it like that)